# NULL/default value for Template vector<typename> iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

I wish to have vector iterators as a part of my class definition in c++ and wish to initialize them to a fixed default value. In the case of pointers, I would have initialized to NULL, not sure what should be done for vector iterators.

```
class ball{
private:
    double x;       
    double v;   
    double timeToNext;  
    vector<ball>::iterator lball, rball;//How should they be initialized?
public:
    ball()  {   //default constructor
    x=-1*INF;
    v=0;
    cout<<"Ball added"<<endl;
    //want to initialize iterators
    }
    void setx(double &pos){x=pos;}
    void setv(double &vel){v=vel;}
    void setTimeToNext()    {
        double tl, tr;
    }
    double getx(){return x;}
    double getv(){return v;}
};
```

Comment: you can use `std::optional<std::vector::iterator<typename>>` but otherwise there is no default value. And it is not a good idea to maintain iterator in a class (unless you maintain vector itself as well, but then answer is obvious)

Comment: The question is too broad. More info needed. Post the code that you want to modify.

Comment: Nullptr is not a good value for an un-initialized pointer. Better is to use some value that, unlike nullptr, a user will not test for, which will throw a segv if de-referenced, and which will stand out like a sore thumb in a debugger. People have used patterns like 0xDEADBEEF.  I think it was a mistake for std::vector's default allocator to supply gratuitous initialization to zeros when it can.

Comment: Alternatively from the code you've posted, it looks like if you call the default constructor on your ball, it creates a bad ball (ie: x = -infinity...). Perhaps from a design perspective it would be better if ball didn't have a default constructor? This may make a lot of your other code that handles balls simpler as well if you can always assume your ball to be in a good state.

Comment: @Slava Thank you for your reply. I now realize that this was a bad choice. My initial goal was to implement a heap of objects using the STL. The heap implemented in <algorithm> requires vectors, hence my strange choice.

Comment: @scohe001 I agree that this is a strange choice, but it stems from the need to process collisions between balls and isolate the balls that have "run away" and will no longer collide. A suggestion in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a bad idea because the vector iterators will be invalidated by any insertion to the vector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> wish to initialize them to a fixed default value. In the case of pointers, I would have initialized to NULL, not sure what should be done for vector iterators.

There is no such thing for `std::vector::iterator`. Instances of `std::vector::iterator` are not sensible unless they are associated with a `std::vector`.

You can leave your `std::vector::iterator` default initialized but then you cannot use it unless it is set to a suitable value that is associated with an instance of `std::vector`.

Answer (score -3):

You could possibly declare this as a member of your class:

```
private:
    static const Vector::iterator null = Vector::iterator();
```

Comment: The standard specifies that doing anything with a default constructed iterator except assigning to it is undefined behavior. Basically it's best to stay away from iterator default constructors.

Comment: a pointer can be compared to `nullptr`, but you cannot compare to a default constructed iterator

Comment: No. Every null pointer will compare as equal. There's no guarantee that two default constructed iterators will compare as equal.

Comment: One obvious distinction is they are useless in bool context, without an extra level of indirection.

Comment: Ok, add a miniature static const vector and make null point to its begin.

Comment: @scohe001 `There's no guarantee that two default constructed iterators will compare as equal` Actually, that is guaranteed for value initialized (which is the initialization used in the answer) forward iterators of same type since C++14. But that's of course not useful in determining whether an iterator has been initialized to a range, or has been value initialized. That's not possible indeed.

Comment: @bipll It wont work, it's UB to compare iterators to different instances of a container.

Comment: If the member iterators are intended to represent a range, and are always compared to each other, then  value initialization would indeed be the correct solution. However, this would be wrong for a different case, so it cannot be presented as a general solution. Also, this static member suggestion is quite pointless.